# Como hacer que guarde en mayuscula

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando guardar en sql server un id de tipo  `uniqueidentifier`  lo genero de esta manera pero me guarda en minuscula

```
set @id=NEWID()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien sabe como hacer que guarde en mayuscula

Answer (score 0):

OJO ese ahi es generado por sha1 o algo asi?, pero si lo necesitas en mayúscula utiliza  UPPER( @variable) en el campo cuando lo vayas a insertar. algo asi set @id=Upper(NEWID());

Comment: Amigo lo mas consejable que yo haria es dejarlo asi pero el momento de mostrarlo es que utilizaria el comando de mayucula UPPER ejemplo: SELECT UPPER( [Id]) from xtabla